# Php exec : output without clean the file

Tags: php, exec, output

I'm calling a php script using exec and I'm trying to make a simple log.

Currently I have this :

```
exec("php script.php $options > temp/log.txt");
```

If I execute once the result is wrote, but if I execute this multiple times it's always replaced by the last call.

Is there a way to just add the output at the end of the .txt, without replacing all the file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with php, you are looking for a shell feature:

```
exec("php script.php $options >> temp/log.txt");
```

Note the double `>>` in there. It appends the redirection instead of overwriting the target.

Comment: Aww, so I was looking to the wrong doc. Thanks you, it's exactly what I wanted.